# Firebase authenticating with routers

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to get the basic Firebase authenticating to work with routers(ui-router) as in [this](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#authenticating-with-routers) example. For some reason I can't get this to work. It rejects me from going to any of the states and when I try to log the error in the run function it responses with [this](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24firebaseAuthProvider%20%3C-%20%24firebaseAuth%20%3C-%20Auth) error.

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.run(["$rootScope", "$location", function($rootScope, $location) {

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireSignIn promise is rejected
        // and redirect the user back to the home page
        if(error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
            $state.go("home");
        }
     });
}]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController',
        resolve: {
            // controller will not be loaded until $waitForSignIn resolves
            // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the factory below
            "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                // $waitForSignIn returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
                return Auth.$waitForSignIn();
            }]
        }
    })
    .state('create', {
        url: '/create',
        templateUrl: 'partials/create.html',
        controller: 'createController',
        resolve: {
            // controller will not be loaded until $waitForSignIn resolves
            // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the factory below
            "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                // $waitForSignIn returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
                return Auth.$waitForSignIn();
            }]
        }
    })
    .state('share', {
        url: '/share',
        templateUrl: 'partials/share.html',
        controller: 'shareController',
        resolve: {
            // controller will not be loaded until $requireSignIn resolves
            // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the factory below
            "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
                // $requireSignIn returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
                // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
                return Auth.$requireSignIn();
            }]
        }
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});

app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
    function($firebaseAuth) {
        return $firebaseAuth();
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the firebase dependency:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'firebase']);
```

Comment: Now I get this error: `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A179)` even though I have added the Firebase JS file

Comment: Thanks, this was the right answer. I also forgot to add AngularFire.

Comment: I couldn't see that piece of code :). Feel free to accept.

Comment: It works as expected when I access routes via the routing system. I want to have multiple pages where you can get without authenticating. The problem: when I'm not authenticated and I access pages by the URL I always get send to the home state, how do I fix this?

Comment: That's a different question, make a new stackoverflow question.